# AWS SAM: java8/gradle app fails with ClassNotFound when deployed (but runs fine locally)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

**Description:**

A java8 app runs locally after doing `sam build; sam local invoke...` but fails with ClassNotFound exception when deployed using `sam package; sam deploy`

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Initialise a Java8/gradle app: `sam init -r java8 -d gradle && cd sam-app`
2. Run `sam build`: `sam build --use-container`
3. Observe that the function runs successfully locally (this fails with the same ClassNotFound exception without the sam build above): `sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --no-event`
4. Package + deploy:

```sh
sam package --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket <some bucket name>
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml  --stack-name java8-gradle-test --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region eu-west-2 --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

5. In AWS Lambda console, find the function `java8-gradle-test-HelloWorldFunction-...`, add an arbitrary test event and click test

**Observed result:**

Execution result: failed

Logs:

```
START RequestId: a5e25d74-4a0d-4763-b7a7-383aeede5c82 Version: $LATEST
Class not found: helloworld.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloworld.App
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)

END RequestId: a5e25d74-4a0d-4763-b7a7-383aeede5c82
REPORT RequestId: a5e25d74-4a0d-4763-b7a7-383aeede5c82  Duration: 58.33 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 69 MB
```

**Expected result:**

The same successful response as when I ran `sam local invoke` for this function.

---

There seems to be some unexpected difference between what's happening with `sam local invoke` and with `sam package`, with the latter not picking up artifacts from `sam build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! This is fixed by using `sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket <some bucket name>` instead, ie not specifying the template file. Obviously `sam local invoke` was picking up the built one, but I wasn't allowing `sam package` to. See explanation on https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/978

Comment: is there fix for samDeploy jenkins plugin ?